# Adding some property to all selected items, which one is the right way and why?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand the the correct way of coding.

My HTML

```
<div id="foo">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

If I want to add class `bar` to all the children divs of div `foo`, which way should I use?

**Option 1** (turned out 3rd)

```
jQuery( '#foo > div' ).addClass( 'bar' );
```

**Option 2**  (turned out 4th fastest)

```
jQuery( '#foo' ).children( 'div' ).addClass( 'bar' );
```

**Option 3** (turned out the fastest)

```
jQuery( '#foo' ).children( 'div' ).each(function(){
    jQuery( this ).addClass( 'bar' )
});
```

**Option 4**  (turned out very close 2nd)

```
jQuery( '#foo > div' ).each(function(){
    jQuery( this ).addClass( 'bar' )
});
```

These all accomplishes what I want.  My Question is,

**Which one should I prefer using over the other? Which cases should I use `.each`?**

**Edit with added snippet which shows using each is better than the other methords**

```js
var t0_start = performance.now();
$('#parent > div').addClass( 'bar' );
var t0_end = performance.now();

var t1_start = performance.now();
$('#parent').children('div').addClass( 'bar' );
var t1_end = performance.now();

var t2_start = performance.now();
$( '#foo > div' ).each(function(){
    $( this ).addClass( 'bar' )
});    
var t2_end = performance.now();

var t3_start = performance.now();
$( '#foo' ).children( 'div' ).each(function(){
    $( this ).addClass( 'bar' )
});    
var t3_end = performance.now();


outcome = 'selector: ' + (t0_end - t0_start);
outcome += "\n";
outcome += 'children(): ' + (t1_end - t1_start)
outcome += "\n";
outcome += 'selector: each(): ' + (t2_end - t2_start)
outcome += "\n";
outcome += 'children(): each(): ' + (t3_end - t3_start)
alert(outcome);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

The result I got was **time for selector: each()** < **time for children(): each()** < **time for selector:** < **time for selector:** < **time for children():**

Comment: Use `each` when you can't accomplish what you're doing without iterating.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The perf tests seem to be getting optimized at runtime and providing some weird numbers. I've broken the tests into separate snippets (iframes) to get more consistent numbers.

**UPDATE 2:** Here's a jsbin wherein I attempt to gain some insight. The selector method is on average faster, but there's overlap. http://jsbin.com/jiluzu/edit?js,output

**UPDATE 3:** jsperf.com is back up! It further supports "selector" as the faster method. http://jsperf.com/jq-selector-vs-children

**ORIGINAL:** In this particular scenario I'd use the first example. It's more succinct and saves you an additional function call. Also, nowadays the "selector" method is more performant as well.

**$('#parent > div');**

```js
var start = performance.now();
$('#parent > div');
var end = performance.now();

outcome = "$('#parent > div'): " + (end - start);
$('#parent').append(outcome);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

**$('#parent').children('div');**

```js
var start = performance.now();
$('#parent').children('div');
var end = performance.now();

outcome = "$('#parent').children('div'): " + (end - start);
$('#parent').append(outcome);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

**$('#foo > div').each()**

```js
var start = performance.now();
$('#foo > div').each(function(){});
var end = performance.now();

outcome = "$('#foo > div').each(): " + (end - start);
$('#parent').append(outcome);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

**$('#foo').children('div').each()**

```js
var start = performance.now();
$('#foo').children('div').each(function(){});
var end = performance.now();

outcome = "$('#foo').children('div').each(): " + (end - start);
$('#parent').append(outcome);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

---

**When to use each()**

Using `each` is helpful in scenarios where you want to do some additional manipulations relative to each item selected.

For example, if we wanted to additionally add a class to the preceding element of each of the selected elements:

```
jQuery( '#foo' ).children( 'div' ).each(function(){
    jQuery( this ).addClass( 'bar' );
    jQuery( this ).prev().addClass( 'foo' );
});
```

Comment: That's interesting. Also `performance.now();` is a neat trick :D

Comment: Pretty decent support, too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Comment: Its funny that in my machine,  the result was something like **selector: 0.3516821879764507** and
**children(): 1.261225906751406**

Comment: @jthomas not really, I am still not sure, my question was not just for the selection time but usage of other functions on the selected elements. I am updating my question based on your answer. Please take a look.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Quite surprised to see each() so much faster. I think the browser may be optimizing at runtime. Putting together another test...

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery, option 2 and 3 are probably quite similar, other than with `each()` you can perform more than one action per element in the selection using a function.

Option 1 is the least performant **in older browsers like IE8, Chrome 5, Opera 9 with older versions of jQuery**. This is because the CSS selector has to be parsed before making the actual selection, which is basically just going to call option 2 anyway.

> ## Why you should never use CSS text selectors
>
> `$("#parent > .child");` and `$("#parent .child");` both need to parse the selector and then just call: `$('#parent').children().filter('.child')` and `$('#parent').filter('.child')` respectively.

More info, including benchmarks for older browsers, [here](http://aahacreative.com/2010/07/19/jquery-fastest-method-find-descendents/) (from 2010).

---

The above is old news for modern browsers and jQuery. CSS selectors are faster nowadays.

Comment: This is no more the case, sizzle using `querySelectorAll()` when possible, which is the case here on modern browsers http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Answer (score -3):

You can go for second option because we can do code comprehensive is      good.

```
 jQuery( '#foo' ).children().addClass( 'bar' );

O/p: <div id="foo">
       <div class="bar"></div>
       <div class="bar"></div>
       <div class="bar"></div>
       <div class="bar"></div>
       <div class="bar"></div>
       <div class="bar"></div>
       <div class="bar"></div>
       <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
```